# Understanding Storm Topology Visualization

Tags: java, apache-storm, directed-acyclic-graphs, apache-storm-topology

I am trying to use Apache Storm 1.0.2 to process a stream of data that is originating from a Kafka Spout. I was trying to use the storm topology visualization that is part of the Storm UI to understand the performance of the pipeline.

Based on the explanations provided in the links below, my understanding of the visualization is this:

1. The thicker the line between the bolts (or spout to bolt) the more traffic is being sent between the components
2. The capacity of the bolt/spout is higher if the color is closer to red. If there are components with high capacity they can prove to be bottlenecks in the pipeline.

However, I was not able to find any documentation regarding the size of the components (ie. diameter of the solid circles in the DAG) in the visualization. The only pattern I noticed was that by reducing the parallelism for a bolt, the size of the component increased in the UI. Are there any details available regarding this feature?

Links referred :

- https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_storm-component-guide/content/ch_storm-topology-tuning.html
- http://www.malinga.me/reading-and-understanding-the-storm-ui-storm-ui-explained/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Storm 1.0.3 and earlier, the diameter of the circles in the topology visualization is solely based on the text width of the node name.

Here's a link to the JavaScript that draws the circles:

https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/4ddd1880dacc9a9c5ab9d760517f6552d993eac8/storm-core/src/ui/public/js/visualization.js#L129,L131

Comment: Since the answer mentioned a version. Do get an update, did the behaviour change after that?